# British Pound "£" sign in TD tag renders as "Â£"

Tags: html

I've made a table, in the table I want to put prices.

My code is like this

```
<tr>
    <td>Course 1</td> <td> £6 </td> <td>£1 week</td>
</tr>
```

But the output is:

```
Course 1     Â£6    Â£1 week
```

How do I make sure that in the cell it says £6 instead of Â£6

Comment: What encoding are you setting in `<meta charset="?">`? If the answer is that you are not setting an encoding you should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a numeric character reference? `&#x00A3;`

You might also be having your document misinterpreted as `latin-1`, when you want `utf-8` [as described here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4383638.htm). Maybe try adding a charset declaration if you want to keep using `£`.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks. I switched to &#x00A, i didn't sett the charset (didn't know i had, i've only really looked into HTML and CSS)

Comment: The charset declaration goes in the `<head></head>` tags. Since you did not set it, you browser might have implied that it was `latin-1`, or similar. I would suggest including a charset declaration, as it usually prevents bugs like this.